# dblclick not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

II have some code here http://jsfiddle.net/ggHwH/ that increases a box border by 1px each time an UP button is pressed and decreases the border by 1px each time a DOWN button is pressed.  Now I'd like to sense a double-click on the down button and have that reduce the border immediately to 0. The problem I'm havng  is that if you try to down click the border one px at a time, you can't help but trigger the double-click, even if you click the down button no faster than about once per second. It seems that I should have to do both clicks in less than about 250ms to trigger the double-click.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

```
   $('#up').click ( function() {
        $('#box').css({'border-top-width' : '+=1px', 'borderRightWidth' :    '+=1px','borderBottomWidth' : '+=1px','borderLeftWidth' : '+=1px'});
    });

$('#down').click ( function() {
    $('#box').css({'border-top-width' : '-=1px', 'borderRightWidth' : '-=1px','borderBottomWidth' : '-=1px','borderLeftWidth' : '-=1px'});
});

$('#down').dblclick ( function() {
    $('#box').css({'border-top-width' : '0px', 'borderRightWidth' : '0px','borderBottomWidth' : '0px','borderLeftWidth' : '0px'});
});
```

Comment: ["It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the `click` and `dblclick` events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two `click` events before the `dblclick` and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable."](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/). So don't do that unless you are full of hate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `dblclick` mixed with `click` isnt a good pratice.

However, for your problem, you can create you "own" `dblclick`. You just need to add 2 var :

```
var isDbl = false;
var timer = null;
```

Then your `click` function will set a timer of 250ms and have a condition :

```
$('#down').click ( function() {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        isDbl = false
    }, 250)
    if(isDbl){
        $('#box').css({'border-top-width' : '0px', 'borderRightWidth' : '0px','borderBottomWidth' : '0px','borderLeftWidth' : '0px'});
        isDbl = false;
    }else{
        $('#box').css({'border-top-width' : '-=1px', 'borderRightWidth' : '-=1px','borderBottomWidth' : '-=1px','borderLeftWidth' : '-=1px'});
    isDbl = true
    }
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ggHwH/4/

Comment: Very nice Karl-André!  Thanks for putting that solution together. Perhaps I can do something small for you in return. I punched up your website and noticed at the top "Web developer/designer interested in every new technologies"  I think a native English speaker would expect to see "Web developer/designer interested in every new technology" or "Web developer/designer interested in all new technologies".  Thanks again for your help.